Can't get rid of "is an unknown property" in application.properties (Eclipse 4.32/Spring 3.3.2)
What I did:

In application.properties added

    application.config.admin-role-name=ADMIN


In build.gradle added

dependencies {
    ...
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}


In *Application.java file annotated the *Application class with

@ConfigurationPropertiesScan


Annotated one of my @Configuration classes with

@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationStartupConfig.class)


Created the following ApplicationStartupConfig class:

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.config")
public class ApplicationStartupConfig {    
    private String adminRoleName;    
    public String getAdminRoleName() {
        return adminRoleName;
    }
    public void setAdminRoleName(String adminRoleName) {
        this.adminRoleName = adminRoleName;
    }
}


Finally, cleaned with gradle, built with gradle and did IDE's Refresh Gradle Project

Unfortunately, even though ApplicationStartupConfig is successfully populated on startup (I can use it via @Autowired in my ApplicationRunner code), Eclipse says:
'application.config.admin-role-name' is an unknown property.    application.properties

Do you need to annotate the String with @Value?

I hope, this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562880/springboot-unknown-property-in-application-properties

@MuhammadqodirMuhsinov, unfortunately it didn't :( After adding metadata, the warnings are gone, however my properties are still non-clickable with ctrl-click like all the others...

Try changing few things
First in application properties changes the name like
application.config.adminRoleName=ADMIN

Then write the config class like
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.config")
@ConstructorBinding
public class ApplicationStartupConfig {  
  
    private String adminRoleName;   

    public ApplicationStartupConfig(String adminRoleName) {
        this.adminRoleName = adminRoleName;
    }

 
    public String getAdminRoleName() {
        return adminRoleName;
    }
    public void setAdminRoleName(String adminRoleName) {
        this.adminRoleName = adminRoleName;
    }
}


I tried this, the application failed with "ApplicationStartupConfig is annotated with @ConstructorBinding but it is defined as a regular bean which caused dependency injection to fail.'
I tried adding an empty constructor as well. This fixed the application failure, but the warnings are still there. :(

@MatildaBentefor Use annotation @ConstructorBinding on class level. I have updated my answer .Can you try that ?

@MatildaBentefor And one more thing, remove @Component annotation

The @ConstructorBinding can't be put onto class, only onto constructors. So I did that, put it on the constructor, but it made no difference.
